# can't add two keys on array_key_exists

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I have this code :

```
 <?php
if ( 'debate' != get_post_type() || (is_user_logged_in() && ! array_key_exists( 'comments', $wp_query->query_vars )) ) {
    comment_form();
}
?>
```

I want to add inside the `array_key_exists(` another key. I've tried this:

`array_key_exists( 'comments','stats', $wp_query->query_vars ))`

But is not working. Is it possible to add two keys inside that function ? If so, how ?

Thank you !

Comment: why not call it twice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not call it twice ?

```
 <?php
if ( 'debate' != get_post_type() || (is_user_logged_in() && ! array_key_exists( 'comments', $wp_query->query_vars ) && ! array_key_exists( 'stats', $wp_query->query_vars )) ) {
    comment_form();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
<?

function multiple_array_key_exists($keys, $arr) {
    $retval = false;
    if (is_array($keys)) {
        foreach ($keys as $item) {
            if (array_key_exists($item, $arr)) {
                $retval = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        $retval = array_key_exists($keys, $arr);
    }
    return $retval;
}

?>
```

If you pass it an array as the first parameter it will check all of them and return true if any one of the values is a key.

`multiple_array_key_exists(array('a', 'b'), array('b' => 1, 'c' => 2, 'd' => 3 ))`